# insert Multiple Checkbox Value different name in mysql database

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox, key-value

i have table admin_rouls

Through it, I control the setting of the admin's permission for the category topics

i try to give each admin permission

for example admin id 9 give him permission to category id 20 can edit or add new topic but cant delete

```
ID  admin_id   cat  can_add  can_edit  can_del
1     9         20     Y        Y       N
2     9         19     N        Y       N
3     9         18     N        N       Y
```

i used this form

```
<form method="post">
<?php 
$GetCats=mysqli_query($db,"select * from section where id_sec = 0");
        while($rowCat=mysqli_fetch_object($GetCats))
{
echo $rowCat->name ;

echo '<div class="pull-left">

ADD
<input type="checkbox"  name="add_cat['.$rowCat->id.']" >

EDIT
<input type="checkbox"  name="edit_cat['.$rowCat->id.']" >

DELETE
<input type="checkbox"  name="del_cat['.$rowCat->id.']" >

</div>';
}
?>
<input type="hidden" name="AdminId" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

post data come like that

`add_cat[50]=on&edit_cat[50]=on&del_cat[50]=on&add_cat[100]=on&edit_cat[100]=on&edit_cat[70]=on&del_cat[70]=on&AdminId=5&submit=save`

I have a problem how insert this data to database table
with many category id same 50 100 70  and option same add_cat edit_cat del_cat

```
ID  admin_id   cat  can_add  can_edit  can_del
1     9         20     Y        Y       N
2     9         19     N        Y       N
3     9         18     N        N       Y
```

any idea ??

Comment: Any help here ?

Comment: any idea here ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to post the category id as your guidelines to POST array, in
   case you not check anything on that row List item
2. And then catch it with for loop

additional : disable error report to make it clean

suggestion : use multi_query to update it to database

I added some ajax to make it more fun

test.php

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
<?php  for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

echo '<div class="pull-left">
<input type="text" name="no[]" value="'.$i.'">
ADD
<input type="checkbox"  name="add_cat['.$i.']" >

EDIT
<input type="checkbox"  name="edit_cat['.$i.']" >

DELETE
<input type="checkbox"  name="del_cat['.$i.']" >

</div>';
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
</form>

<div id="data">
    
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'test-ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                $("#data").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And test-ajax.php

```
<?php 

//print_r($_POST);
error_reporting(0);
$no   = $_POST['no'];
$add  = $_POST['add_cat'];
$edi  = $_POST['edit_cat'];
$del  = $_POST['del_cat'];
echo '<br>';
for($i = 0; $i < count($no); $i++){
    echo $no[$i] .' - '.$add[$i].' - '.$edi[$i].' - '.$del[$i].'<br>';
}
```